# How to remove second word with a line break form array

Tags: python, regex, string, list, split

How can remove 2.50\n from this array?

`line = ['1.60\n2.50\n2.15', '1.80\n2.20\n1.90']`

Tried with split, rsplit but I can't remove

I need result to be
`line = ['1.60\n2.15', '1.80\n1.90']`
Can regex do it?

Comment: `line[0].replace("2.50\n","")` is one way you could

Comment: You could call `splitlines()` and discard the second item

Comment: This is for a specific value. But what if is a different second value in a long array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the number that you want to remove from the string is not always the same you can use something like:

```
new_line = []
for entry in line:
    lst = entry.split('\n')
    lst.pop(1)
    entry = "\n".join(lst)
    new_line.append(entry)
```

Comment: This returns me 
`1.60 
2.15` but I need ['1.60\n2.15']

Comment: Yes. When I print without this code I get ['1.60\n2.15']. I will test it now in the rest of the code.

Comment: `line = ["\n".join(lst)]` then, if it needs to be a list

Comment: This returns me only the first string. Please if you can look at the edited question.

Comment: I updated the solution for this